# AddTransient to IServiceCollection when a generic type is unknown

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, asp.net-web-api2

In my WebApi Core, the Repository is by constructor injection.

```
//In the application, Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:myConnection"]));
    services.AddDataAccess<MyContext>();
    services.AddMvc();
}

//In the controller
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    readonly IRepository<Customer> _repository;

    public ValuesController(IRepository<Customer> repository)
    {
       _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

See below the generic DAL. I got an error on : *services.AddTransient
Using the generic type 'GenericEntityRepository' requires 2 type arguments*

Then I need somehting like this :

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<TEntity>), typeof(GenericEntityRepository<TEntityContext, TEntity>));
```

but when I do this I get the errors :

- TEntity not found
- TEntityContext must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TContext' in the generic type 
  or method 'GenericEntityRepository'

I don't see at all how solve this.

```
//In my Generic DAL
public static class ServiceCollectionExtentions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddDataAccess<TEntityContext>(this IServiceCollection services)
        where TEntityContext : EntityContextBase<TEntityContext>
    {
        RegisterDataAccess<TEntityContext>(services);
        return services;
    }

    private static void RegisterDataAccess<TEntityContext>(IServiceCollection services)
        where TEntityContext : EntityContextBase<TEntityContext>
    {
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericEntityRepository<>));
    }
}

public class EntityContextBase<TContext> : DbContext 
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public EntityContextBase(DbContextOptions<TContext> options) : base(options) { }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    void Load();
}

public class GenericEntityRepository<TContext,TEntity> 
    : EntityRepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity> 
        where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
        where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    public GenericEntityRepository() : base(new TContext()) { }
}

public abstract class EntityRepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity> 
    : RepositoryBase<TContext>, IRepository<TEntity>
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
{
    protected EntityRepositoryBase(TContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    protected IQueryable<TEntity> QueryDb()
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = Context.Set<TEntity>();

        return query;
    }

    public virtual void Load()
    {
        var result = QueryDb();
        result.Load();
    }
}

public class GenericEntityRepository<TContext,TEntity> 
    : EntityRepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity> 
        where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
        where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    public GenericEntityRepository() : base(new TContext()) { }
}
```

Comment: Why do you do a `new TContext()` when constructing a Repository? That's turning the UoW pattern on its head. Also, how would that be configured (connectionstring)?

Comment: When you work back from the ValuesController it's clear that the DI has no way of determining TContext. You never specify it anywhere and it can't be derived.

Comment: That's the point, I don't want Uow (I'd like avoid, not really needed for EF but it's an another debate). I'd like when I create the repo create the instance of the DbContext.

Comment: A DbContext is a UoW, like it or not. You can have MyContext injected into your Repos and it is Scoped, not Transient. As it probably should be.

Comment: What is your suggestion to inject the DbContext (Scoped) into a generic Repo ? The goal at the end it's make a nuget package with all my repository methods

Comment: Well, I can't see the forrest for the trees here... Maybe rethink your design with the aim to minimize dependencies.